# Can i run Internet Explorer inside a Windows Server Container?

Tags: internet-explorer, docker, windows-server-container

I want to realise my dream of having containers for my web app and containers with selenium inside testing it. Then i can massively parallelise my browser testing just by creating a cluster of containers.

Is it possible to run Internet Explorer in a Windows Server Container?

Thanks

Comment: Wow. I have exactly same requirement as yours. One possible way would be to run headless or Run remote Selenium server. But that would require refactoring of Tests. So, running IE inside container is desirable for me as well. I don't want to refactor my tests now. Not until Microsoft Releases this officially.

Comment: Just found this article released this month - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/manage_images

Comment: I'm pretty interested in this as well and am working on getting an example running.  Looks like you still need to put it on a Windows host OS however